# Is there anything at the front end that could cause slow server response time?

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, hosting

Our Wordpress website currently has an extremely slow server response time; it routinely returns in 10 - 12 seconds. Everything else on the site is optimised and until recently it was returning a Google page speed insights score of 98.

This sounds like an issue with the host to me (especially as it was running fine until recently). Is there anything else that it's likely to be?

Comment: You need to do some diagnostics. webpagetest.org, look at top to see what's taking CPU, find a way of looking at I/O. Wordpress is a CPU and memory hog, and many plugins are poorly written. Caching at or before the web server level can help a lot, but you often have to rewrite the caching headers as Wordpress themes tend to be rubbish at setting them correctly. Some tips on [Nginx caching here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-4-wordpress-website-optimization/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you run it on shared hosting? Has you tried reaching your hosting provider support on that?

You might also test it with services like [webpagetest.org](https://www.webpagetest.org/) to see if it also lags from other locations.

Besides you can get some or sort of webserver test suites, and temporary place it on your web server to see where the problem is. But if thats a shared hosting I say thats not your problem, just ask them to check and solve it.

Comment: It's on dedicated cloud hosting; it runs fine on my development server.

Comment: @BFWebAdmin If it's managed, you should ask support to resolve this. If you manage it on your own you have to check your configuration and do some testing on that server.
Also make sure to check your logs for webserver load. Your public server might be overloaded or under attack.

Comment: Have you checked it on your development server with similar load as your production web server has?